# Compilation Error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]|

Tags: c++, arrays

Error shows in below line

```
int sum = arr[i][j] + arr[i][j+1] + arr[j+2] + arr[i+1][j+1] + arr[i+2][j] + arr[i+2][j+1] + arr[i+2][j+2];
```

My Code is below,

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

int arr[6][6];

for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<6;j++) cin>>arr[i][j];

for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    {

       int sum = arr[i][j] + arr[i][j+1] + arr[j+2] + arr[i+1][j+1] + arr[i+2][j] + arr[i+2][j+1] + arr[i+2][j+2];
       cout<<sum;
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `arr[j+2]` ? What happened to the 2nd dimension?

Comment: I good idea would be to show the **actual** error.

Comment: @Ted, the error is in the title.

Comment: @paxdiablo Are you sure? `[-fpermissive|` is nothing I've got thrown at me - even though I use it as an option all the time. I mean, the **actual** error. Not something interpreted by OP.

Comment: @Ted, the actual error is `invalid conversion from int* to int`, the `-fpermissive` is added to show which warning/error flag is the one that caused it. You can see it (in `g++`) with `void xyzzy() { int x = 1; int y = &x; }`: `pax.cpp:1:35: error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]`.

Comment: @paxdiablo Ah ... I thought that part was a trick to lure people in. Why can't  `int` and `int*` just be friends? ... Your answer got my vote btw.

Comment: Take another look at the error message produced by your compiler. Most compilers identify *where* the error occurred, including the character position. That should help you zero in on the problematic term.

Answer (score 3):

```
int sum = arr[i][j] + arr[i][j+1] + arr[j+2] + ...
//                                  ^^^^^^^^
```

You have a dimension missing here (above the `^` markers), `arr[j+2]` is an integer *pointer* (technically it's an array, but it *decays* to an integer pointer here) which is what your compiler is complaining about with its `invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int'` output.

Based on the code, it's hard to tell what the other dimension *should* be, but it definitely should be something like:

```
arr[i+SOMETHING][j+2]
```